# CAML Query all SharePoint documents modified in a given month

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I want to list the all the files that were created, or modified in a given month in a SharePoint Online library. I would like to further recursively include any files in folders ( but excluding the folders themselves).  There are a few issues with the (get-PnPListItems) query below

1) it doesn't work! It brings all the files in my test root library that were created yesterday.

```
 $query = `
 "<View><Where>  `
   <And>`
      <Geq>`
         <FieldRef Name='Modifed' /> <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'` 
          Type='DateTime'>01/04/2017 12:00:00 AM</Value> `
      </Geq> `
      <Leq> `
        <FieldRef Name='Modifed' /> `
         <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>01/05/2017 12:00:00 
        AM</Value> `
     </Leq> `
    </And> `
   </Where></View>"
```

2) I ideally want to use variable parameters for the start and end dates I am thinking of this and adding days to get the following on the range. However, I guess this could be improved upon.

```
   $startDate = [Datetime]::new(2017,04,01)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your overall CAML query should be as below:

```
$query = 
 "<View><Where>  
   <And>
      <Geq>
         <FieldRef Name='Modifed' /> <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'
          Type='DateTime'>2017-04-01T00:00:00Z</Value> 
      </Geq> 
      <Leq> 
        <FieldRef Name='Modifed' /> 
         <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>2017-05-01T00:00:00Z</Value> 
     </Leq> 
    </And> 
   </Where></View>"
```

You have to format the date to ISO 8601 format as below even though you have mentioned `IncludeTimeValue=FALSE`:

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

In SSOM, we used to do it using

`var date = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(startDate)` method

In case of SPO powershell, we need to first use the `Get-Date` method and then format the date string.

So, your code would be:

```
$startDate = Get-Date "01/04/2017" 
$startDatestring = $startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
$endDate = Get-Date "01/05/2017"
$endDatestring = $endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

So your CAML query would be somewhat as below where we pass the date formatted string :

```
$query = 
 "<View><Where>  
   <And>
      <Geq>
         <FieldRef Name='Modifed' /> <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'
          Type='DateTime'>" + startDatestring + "</Value> 
      </Geq> 
      <Leq> 
        <FieldRef Name='Modifed' /> 
         <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>" + endDatestring + "</Value> 
     </Leq> 
    </And> 
   </Where></View>"
```

Comment: thanks very much  the $query = "<View><Query><Where>  `
   <And> `
      <Geq> `
         <FieldRef Name='Modifed' /> <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' `
          Type='DateTime'>" + $startDatestring + "</Value> `
      </Geq> `
      <Leq> `
        <FieldRef Name='Modifed' /> `
         <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>" + $endDatestring + "</Value> `
     </Leq> `
    </And> `
   </Where></Query></View>"  The issue I have is Get-PnPListItems needs  -fields to get Modifed returned but this doesn't work with -Query parameter

Comment: Instead you have the more cumbersome approach: $items =  Get-PnPListItem -List Resources -Query $query -Web $locationWeb   -Fields "FileLeafRef", "Modified" | %{new-object psobject -property  @{Id = $_.Id;   Name = $_["FileLeafRef"]; Modified = $_["Modified"]}} | select Id, Name, Modified; Foreach($item in $items) {write-host $item.Modified.ToString()} Oh well thanks anyway as I do prefer the CAML method.